# How to define a custom key in PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to define a two dimension array like below:

```
   [40.1][John]
   [40.2][Jane]
   [40.7][Mary]       
   [40.10][Sara]
```

in other words I want to define an array with custom key. Later I need to access to the array values with the custom key. for instance :

```
   echo(myarray[40.2]);
```

And I need to generate the array dynamically from XML , since the values are coming from a XML file.
The XML file which I want to generate the array from is like below:

```
    <rules>

<rule>
    <id>40.1</id>
    <regex><![CDATA[/(?:\)\s*when\s*\d+\s*then)/]]></regex>
</rule>
<rule>
    <id>40.2</id>
    <regex><![CDATA[/(?:"\s*(?:#|--|{))/]]></regex>
</rule>
```

How should I create the array with above characteristics?

Comment: PHP has a wonderful built-in data type called a **string** that you can use for key names in an associative array. You should try it.

Comment: All I can say is `$test["40.1"]["john"] = array();` without seeing some code and understanding how you are retrieving the xml

Comment: @MartinBean Actually PHP doesn't know data-types, at all :P Everything is just a bunch of C-strings that get detected on call and handed in their own manner which PHP seems most fit for the operation. This makes PHP a very easy and flexible language, but also introduced the most horrid (sometimes undetectable) problems.

Comment: Amir, what will $generatedArray['40.2'] contain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this very easily by creating an associative array

```
$myarray = array(
  "40.1" => "John",
  "40.2" => "Jane",
  "40.7" => "Mary",
  "40.10" => "Sara"
);
```

Later on you can iterate over this array with a foreach loop

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
  echo "<p>" . $key . " = " . $value . "</p>";
}
```

This will output to the screen

```
40.1 = John
40.2 = Jane
40.7 = Mary
40.10 = Sara
```

To create a new array and add items to is as easy as doing this

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray[$newkey] = $newvalue;
```

For a two dimensional array, you can define them like this

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray[$key] = array();
$myarray[$key]['John'] = 'some value';
$myarray[$key]['Jane'] = 'another value';
$myarray[$key2] = array();
$myarray[$key2]['Mary']= 'yet another value';
```

Or as a short cut

```
$myarray = array(
  $key => array(
   'John' => 'some value',
   'Jane' => 'another value',
  ),
  $key2 = array(
   'Mary' => 'yet another value'
  )
);
```

Comment: I said that I need to generate the array dynamically, since the values & keys are coming from a XML file.

Comment: I've amended my answer to answer that question.

Comment: @AmirSa Filling the key-field with a variable (`[40.1][$value]`) works the same way. It will provide the handler with a string that can relate to that point in the array. What's your actual problem with it? :)

Comment: @Robbert the last code section work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with associative array key => value.

```
$arr = array('40.1' => 'John', '40.2' => 'Jane', '40.7' => 'Mary', ...);
echo $arr['40.1']; // will return John
```

If you think to extend the data in the feature, you can do it with nested arrays

```
$arr = array(
'40.1' => array('name' => 'John', 'eyes' => 'green');
'40.2' => array('name' => 'Jane', 'eyes' => 'blue');
);
```

You can access nested array like this:

```
echo $arr['40.2']['eyes'] // return blue
```

You can see also PHP documentation about arrays [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

## Array keys

**Notice**! Do not use "float" as type for array keys.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b",
    1.5  => "c",
    true => "d",
);
var_dump($array);
```

Output will be:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

## Two-dimensional arrays

You can create your array like this:

```
$data = [
   '40.2' => [
       'John' => [ 
           // and now this is second dimension
       ] 
   ]
];
```

Add aditional stuff:

```
$data['40.2']['John'][] = ; // just append value 
// or 
$data['40.2']['John']['sex'] = 'Male'; // store it with key
```

Or if you need to store scalar values, you can define array like this:

```
$data = [
   '40.2' => [
       'John' => 'male' // storing scalar values  
   ]
];
```

Sorry, If I misunderstood your question.